# FactoryGirl / Bot image definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, factory

I have a feature test. In this feature test I need to load some data into the test database: `let!(:product1) { create(:product) }`

I am using FactoryBot to create and save the :product object to the database:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do
    name 'Master Coat'
    color 'black'
    size 'M'
    price '870'
    available true
    order 1
    image_1 '/assets/images/test_image.jpeg'
    image_2 '/assets/images/test_image.jpeg'
    image_3 '/assets/images/test_image.jpeg'
    image_4 '/assets/images/test_image.jpeg'
    image_5 '/assets/images/test_image.jpeg'
    image_6 '/assets/images/test_image.jpeg'
  end
end
```

And I run my RSpec test:

```
  describe 'GET #detail' do
    it 'should return only products with a specified name' do
        visit detail_path(name: 'Master Coat')
    end
  end
```

However, I get an error because my view needs to generate images 1, 2, etc., which in my real app is loaded from AWS through a url. But in my tests I don't want to send requests to AWS since I am not testing the images. The image that is loaded is irrelevant. I just want to have a dummy image in my `app/assets/images/test_image.jpeg` directory and have FactroyBot use that image for all tests, but I am having trouble getting it to work because I am incorrectly specifying the path to the image and FactoryBot gives me an error of:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       The asset "assets/images/test_image.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

I've tried several different ways to get it to work. Whats the proper way to specify the url to my images folder so that FactoryBot can then retrieve the dummy image? And is this the best way to do it or is their a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the path. When you use `image_tag('test_image.jpeg')` rails will look in `app/assets/images`. You can also just place the files in the public directory and they will be served statically instead of going through the pipeline.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do
    name 'Master Coat'
    color 'black'
    size 'M'
    price '870'
    available true
    order 1
    (1..6).each {|n| send "image_#{n}", 'test_image.jpeg' }
  end
end
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I first tried without the path and it didn't work, but now I found out it wasn't working because of another error. In any case, this works like a charm and love how you shortened my Factory with a block :).